# MySQL createStatement() memory leak

Tags: c++, mysql, memory-leaks

I´m running a big code with lots of MYSQL database access that and I´m noticing a memory leak that consumes the whole server memory after one day running.

By isolating pieces I end up with the following test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>


#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main() {

    try
    {
        sql::Driver *driver = NULL;
        sql::Connection *connection = NULL;

        driver = get_driver_instance();

        connection = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "pass");
        connection->setSchema("myschema");
        connection->setAutoCommit(true);

        while (true)
        {
            std::string sql("INSERT INTO tablename ('field1', 'field2', 'field3') VALUES ('1', '2', '3')");
            sql::Statement *stmt;
            stmt = connection->createStatement();
            stmt->execute(sql.c_str());
            stmt->close();
            std::cout << sql << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error occurred: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown failure occurred." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As the main `while` runs, the process memory usage starts increasing like 1Mb per minute.

Using `valgrid --leak-check=full` I got the following result after hitting  to exit from the main loop:

```
==11988== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==11988==    at 0x57F5D6D: recv (recv.c:29)
==11988==    by 0x5B1B022: vio_read (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0)
==11988==    by 0x5B1B0A4: vio_read_buff (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0)
==11988==    by 0x5AFA702: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0)
==11988==    by 0x5AFA976: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0)
==11988==    by 0x5AFB6A3: my_net_read (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0)
==11988==    by 0x5AF151C: cli_safe_read (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0)
==11988==    by 0x5AF2A15: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0)
==11988==    by 0x5AF43A5: mysql_real_query (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0)
==11988==    by 0x4F15BEE: sql::mysql::NativeAPI::LibmysqlStaticProxy::real_query(st_mysql*, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7.1.1.3)
==11988==    by 0x4F176F5: sql::mysql::NativeAPI::MySQL_NativeConnectionWrapper::query(sql::SQLString const&) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7.1.1.3)
==11988==    by 0x4F10579: sql::mysql::MySQL_Statement::do_query(sql::SQLString const&) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7.1.1.3)
==11988== 
==11988== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11988==     in use at exit: 333,479 bytes in 1,869 blocks
==11988==   total heap usage: 5,566 allocs, 3,697 frees, 1,100,674 bytes allocated
==11988== 
==11988== 144,880 bytes in 1,811 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 42 of 42
==11988==    at 0x4C2C12F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11988==    by 0x4EC4334: sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection::createStatement() (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7.1.1.3)
==11988==    by 0x4011B7: main (test.cpp:32)
==11988== 
==11988== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11988==    definitely lost: 144,880 bytes in 1,811 blocks
==11988==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11988==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11988==    still reachable: 188,599 bytes in 58 blocks
==11988==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11988== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==11988== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==11988== 
==11988== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11988== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So, am I doing something wrong or is this a know MYSQL bug ? How to fix the code and/or mySQL ?

I´m running MySql 5.6.27-0ubuntu1 running on Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `delete stmt`. Better would be to use a `std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement>`.

(See e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-query.html)

Try

```
std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(connection->CreateStatement());
```

Comment: Good point - the pointers are remaining around - and certainly smart pointers are the way to go. I tried `std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt = std::move(connection->createStatement()) ` but is not going though... Can you please help ?